# Program works in Eclipse but when I export to runnable JAR it doesnt. FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, audio, jar

I tried to make a runnable JAR, but for some reason I couldn't get my game to play. I did some research and ran it through my command prompt to try to find the error and I got this below. So obviously I know the issue I just need to fix it. I have the audio file in my res folder which is in my src. So if it is already in the program I can't figure out why I would get this error. Thoughts?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at builder.AudioPlayer.playMenuSound(AudioPlayer.java:20)
        at builder.Game.<init>(Game.java:56)
        at builder.Game.main(Game.java:61)
```

```
package builder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class AudioPlayer {

    private static Clip play;

    public static void playMenuSound()
    {
        try {
            //AudioInputStream menuSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/res/introSong.wav")); //Take in audio from res folder
            AudioInputStream menuSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("introSong.wav"));
            play = AudioSystem.getClip(); //
            play.open(menuSound); //Play the sound
            FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN); //Get control of volume
            volume.setValue(1.0f); //0.0 - 1.0 volume
            play.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //Loop once clip is over
        }catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void playGameSound()
    {
        try {
            //AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/res/inGame.wav")); //Take in audio from res folder
            AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("inGame.wav"));
            play = AudioSystem.getClip(); //
            play.open(gameSound); //Play the sound
            FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN); //Get control of volume
            volume.setValue(0.5f); //0.0 - 1.0 volume
            play.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //Loop once clip is over
        }catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void stopMusic()
    {
        play.close(); //Stop music
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the snippet of your code where you're trying to access the `introSong.wav` file?

Comment: @SafeerAnsari I edited above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is where you're trying to instantiate your file with a `new` reference, here:

```
AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/res/inGame.wav"));
```

Instead of doing that, you need to get your file as a `resource` using a ClassLoader, since it is located inside the resource (res) folder.

Here is how your code should look like:

```
AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("inGame.wav"));
```

Same should be done in with your `introSong.wav` in the `playMenuSound()` method. The code should look something like

```
AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("introSong.wav"));
```

I really hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry I am new to programming. I got an error on the `this` says I can't use static in this context. So I guess what exactly is `this` referencing?

Comment: As in `private AudioPlayer audio = new AudioPlayer();` ?

Comment: I've updated the solution, removed `this` reference from the solution.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
 at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at builder.AudioPlayer.playMenuSound(AudioPlayer.java:20)
 at builder.Game.<init>(Game.java:56)
 at builder.Game.main(Game.java:61)`

Comment: Did you replace `this` with the `class.getClassLoader()` reference as updated in my solution above?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with the following form for setting up Clips. Perhaps it will work for you.

```
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("audio/" + filename);
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(ais);
```

The method `getResource` returns a `URL`. The method `getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream`. A `URL` works as a way to address a file within a jar.

In this example, the file in which the code resides is a parent to the folder "/audio" and the audio resource is in the "/audio" folder.

The following form works for me if you desire to call the loader as a static method.

```
    URL url = AudioPlayer.class.getResource("audio/" + filename);
```